# drawLines method produces strange effect on scaled Canvas

Tags: android, graphics, paint, android-canvas

I have a custom View subclass that allows the user to sketch out a Chinese character. The line coordinates are saved to a float array (x1, y1, x2, y2, x2, y2, x3, y3...) which is scaled to unit size, i.e. all coordinates are values between zero and one. This makes it easier when later on the sketch is animated in a view of a different size. It also helps to compare what was drawn with another animation in the same coordinate space. The coordinates are flipped vertically, also to aid with that comparison.

What that means is that when the lines are sketched in the View's onDraw method the Canvas has to be scaled up and translated before a call to drawLines plots the sketch.

On all devices in the office (Android ~2.3) everything displays normally, and the emulator is okay too. However, two users with Samsung Galaxy S2 phones, who both report recently upgrading to Android 4, find that the lines appear "gappy" as shown below:

[image: Illustrates problem]

I've tried switching away from drawLines to using Path objects instead, but in this case the users reported that the lines didn't show up at all!

Here's how I configure the paint:

```
    paint = new Paint();        
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(kTCDrawPathWidth);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Join.BEVEL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

And this is where I plot the sketch:

```
    RectF frame = getDrawingBounds();   
    canvas.drawRoundRect(frame, 3, 3, drawAreaFramePaint);      
    canvas.drawRoundRect(frame, 3, 3, drawAreaFrameBorderPaint);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(frame.left, frame.top+frame.height());
    canvas.scale(frame.width(), -frame.height());

    for (TCPath path : paths)
        canvas.drawLines(path.getLines(), paint);

    if (drawingPath!=null)
        canvas.drawLines(drawingPath.getLines(), paint);

    canvas.restore();
```

Any glaring issues there? Was there a change to Paint/Canvas behaviour in Android 4?

Comment: don't you need to scale the kTCDrawPathWidth, ?paint.setStrokeWidth(kTCDrawPathWidth/frame.left);

Comment: The path width is set to a value that's proportional to the coordinate system, in this case 0.018f. The line widths appear to be correct in both the normal case (my devices) and this strange case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using hardware acceleration, try turning it off for your custom view that is doing the draw (myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE). You can also try disabling anti-aliasing, see if that helps.

Otherwise I would suggest giving Path another shot.

Comment: That did indeed fix it. I'm trying to support earlier API versions and this method is API 11+, so I had to wrap it in a try...catch (NoMethodError) block. Anyhow, the problem has only manifested in Android OS 4 so that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of doing a try...catch you should just if off of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT - faster that way :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is right or not but just in case:

```
canvas.scale(frame.width(), -frame.height());
```

What is the minus sing doing in front of `frame.height()`?

what are you subtracting from?

Comment: First I translate by the height, then scale by negative-height. This flips the drawing upside down. It's just convenient that way, because the drawing will be compared with another one that's also flipped. As you can see, the drawing is in the right position - it just looks a bit strange!